# Cannot read property of undefined - React Native with Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Im creating posts and saving in firebase successfully but now im trying to call them in my "Feed" page so i can show all the posts that are made in the firebase under the "posts" collection which are created and existing in the firebase but it says that values are undefined.
**This is my post creating function:**

```
addPost = async ({ text, localUri }) => {
        const remoteUri = await this.uploadPhotoAsync(localUri, `photos/${this.uid}/${Date.now()}`);

        return new Promise((res, rej) => {
            this.firestore.collection("posts").add({
                text,
                uid: this.uid,
                timestamp: this.timestamp,
                image: remoteUri
            })
                .then(ref => {
                    res(ref);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    rej(error);
                })
        })
    }
```

**And this is how i want to call it on the "Feed" page:**

```
export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

  state = {
    posts: {}
  }

  unsubscribe = null;


  componentDidMount() {
    const post = this.props.uid || Fire.shared.uid;

    this.unsubscribe = Fire.shared.firestore.collection("posts").doc(post).onSnapshot(doc => {
      this.setState({ posts: doc.data() });
    });
  };
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribe();
  }

 
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.feedItem}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "space-between", alignItems: "center" }}>
            <View>
              <Text style={styles.timestamp}>{moment(this.state.posts.timestamp).fromNow()}</Text>
            </View>
            <Ionicons name="ios-more" size={24} color="#7378BB" />
          </View>
          <Text style={styles.post}>{this.state.posts.text}</Text>

          <Image source={this.state.posts.image} style={styles.postImage} resizeMode="cover" />

          <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
            <Ionicons name="ios-heart-empty" size={24} color="#73788B" style={{ marginRight: 16 }} />
            <Ionicons name="ios-chatboxes" size={24} color="#73788B" />
          </View>

        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And i get error

> Cannot read property 'timestamp' (since its the first value) of
> undefined.

The addPost function is inside Fire.js, and in my HomePage.js i import it as Fire from './Fire.js'.

Also in the `const post = this.props.uid || Fire.shared.uid;` i dont really think i need to get user id to the posts so what should i put there?

**Styles:**

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#EFECF4"
  },
  header: {
    paddingTop: 34,
    paddingBottom: 16,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: "#EBECF4",
    shadowColor: "#454D65",
    shadowOffset: { height: 5 },
    shadowRadius: 15,
    shadowOpacity: 0.2,
    zIndex: 10
  },
  headerTitle: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: "bold"
  },
  feedItem: {
    backgroundColor: "#FFF",
    borderRadius: 5,
    padding: 8,
    flexDirection: "row",
    marginVertical: 8,
  },
  avatar: {
    width: 36,
    height: 36,
    borderRadius: 18,
    marginRight: 16,
  },
  name: {
    fontSize: 15,
    fontWeight: "500",
    color: "#454D65"
  },
  timestamp: {
    fontSize: 11,
    color: "#C4C6CE",
    marginTop: 4
  },
  post: {
    marginTop: 16,
    fontSize: 14,
    color: "#838899"
  },
  postImage: {
    width: undefined,
    height: 150,
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginVertical: 16
  }

});
```

Comment: FYI there's no need to use `new Promise` to wrap other things that are promises. You can use the promise chain itself to return what you want to the caller.

Comment: and how to do that im new to react native

Comment: It doesn't matter what framework you're using - I'm just talking plain javascript promises here.

Comment: ahm i see, but do you have an idea why it says that 'timestamp' is undefined?

Comment: I suggest editing the question to state very clearly what you expect this code to do. What is the specific value of timestamp that you are expecting here?

Comment: timestamps are automatically converted to numbers that represent the date and time created, i just dont understand how to call the "posts" values from database because they exist with the given values for example the text, the photo and the timestamp are being saved in the database, but i dont know how to call them to show them on my "feed"page

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question.  What is the specific value you're expecting?  If you don't know, then we're flying in the dark here.

Comment: idk what you mean by specific value?

Comment: because i commented the timestamp part and it says undefined for the "text" as well

Comment: You're getting undefined, I get that.  What are you expecting to get instead? Please edit the question to be specific.

Comment: to get the value that is created under "posts" collection from the firebase

Comment: OK, could you **edit the question** to make that very clear?

Comment: allright, i added that values are created in the "posts" collection and i want to call them from firebase to my "feed" page